CPM Modulation and Demodulation, How to find the sampling rate to find the Power spectral density of the modulated signal?
I have specified:

Bandwidth BRF = 25KHz
M(modulation order) = 8
h(modulation index) = 1/2
L(overlap factor) = 2

I know that:

fs = 2BRF/(Bnorm*NS)
Bnorm= normalized frequency
Ns = upsampling factor = 8

But to find Bnorm I have to plot 3dB PSD to get Bnorm. What should be the initial fs?

not a programming problem. try the stack exchange for electronics or whatever looks appropriate on https://stackexchange.com/sites
